# How to add NA rows to an incomplete dataframe based on an complete index?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

For the given incomplete dataframe `df` and complete index `t`:

```
t = seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:05:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 01:00:00"), by = '5 min')
index<-t[c(1,2,4:7,9,12)]
a<-(1:8)
b<-(1:8)
df<-data.frame(index,a,b)
```

By my way, the missing rows can be added by the following code:

```
index<-t           #complete index
a<-vector('numeric',12)
a<-NA
b<-vector('numeric',12)
b<-NA
empty_df<-data.frame(index,a,b)         # build an complete NA dataframe
for (i in 1:12) {
 if(!(df$index[i]==empty_df$index[i]))
 df<-rbind(rbind(df[1:i-1,],empty_df[i,]),df[i:length(df$index),])}  # comparison and revison
```

However, my solution have two problems:

1. Cannot deal with the situation when the first row is missing.
2. When the dataframe is large, the computing will take hours.

So I'm wondering if there is any easier way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `merge` (`base R`) or `left_join` (from `dplyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(index = t) %>%
              left_join(., df)
```

---

Or join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[data.table(index=t), on = "index"]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want. By the way, is `left_join(data.frame(index=t), df)` the same as your `data.frame(index = t) %>%
              left_join(., df)`?

Comment: @YQ.Wang  Yes, you are right.  I just used the `%>%` to show how it can be chained in dplyr.